# i have problem when i use Docker container is not using my local html file

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers

First i create normal Docker file and used

FROM nginx:latest

COPY .  /usr/share/nginx/html

inside Dockerfile

it create images and containers perfectly

but my friend by mistake write this in the terminal:

docker run -d -p 80:80 docker/getting-started

every time I create image or container will let me go to this website
the first code i write after i delete the images and continers:
docker build .

my image command :
docker build -t image name .

my container command :
docker run -d -p 80:80  Image ID

note: the container was run my HTML file normal but my friend used that command I don't know  why but  I need to fix it i just want my container run my HTML file

[code picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTI7b.png)

[The wrong website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ic1j.png)

Comment: What's the specific error you're encountering; are you seeing the "hello world" content instead of your application content?  Did you stop and delete the "getting started" container?  You attached two PNG files to the question, which I'm guessing you're referencing via HTML `<img>` tags; are you `COPY`ing them into your image?

Comment: yes I did delete both image and container and still it's on getting started


 
it's a simple html that shows 2 videos it's just for a project in my collage and I faced this problem

Answer (score 0):

Stop the docker engine and remove all images and then built the image

Comment: we  tried to restart docker engine and same problem

Comment: Can you try with a new docker profile and check if it is also having the same issue

Comment: I tried another device and it's worked